# How to Find specific text word using Excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I need to find a specific word from an Excel file. I want to search row by row, and if the word is found, skip 2 rows down and copy the next 20 rows and loop to the next word.

```
Sub Example4()

Dim FilePath As Workbook    
Dim wsheet As Worksheet
Dim i, lcount, lcount2 As Integer
 Dim cell, rgFound As Range
Dim Found As Range, LastRow As Long


 Set FilePath = Workbooks.Open("D:\SLC.txt")
  Dim rowVal As Integer
    rowVal = 1

    For lcount = 1 To FilePath.Sheets("SLC").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row

    Set rgFound = Range("A1:A1048576").Find("TXN. NO     TXN SEQ", ThisWorkbook.Sheets(), Cells(rowVal, 1))


            FilePath.Cells(wsheet.Range(rowVal).End(xlDown).Row + 3).xlCopy

            wbook2.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
            wbook2.SaveAs ("D:\SLC_Copied.xlsx")
            wbook2.Close

   rowVal = rgFound1.Row

   Debug.Print lcount
   Next lcount


End Sub
```

Comment: Can you update your post with the code you've tried so far, and describe where it's failing?

Comment: Set rgFound = Range("A1:A1048576").Find("TXN. NO     TXN SEQ", ThisWorkbook.Sheets(), Cells(rowVal, 1))

Comment: Thank you. Where is it failing? How isn't it working?

Comment: @AllenW.Marx  Previous my comment it shows me type miss-match error (Run-time error 13) but my data type are correct

Comment: Try putting ``Option Explicit`` in your code, above ``Sub Example4()``. Then try running your code. You should also try importing ``SLC.txt`` as CSV with Excel. I'm not sure if you can do what you're trying to do with a text file. [Here's a link on how to do that](https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/import-export-text-files.html)

Comment: No need to loop through the rows. You can use [.Find and .FindNext](http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2018/01/05/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/) to achieve what you want

Comment: yes, it's text file but I open it Set FilePath = Workbooks.Open("D:\SLC.txt") it's is opening CSV format it's not my issues.

Answer (score 0):

As Siddharth Rout suggested, use Find and FindNext.
Try to choose variable names appropriate to their type, calling a workbook object FilePath is confusing to others trying to understand your script.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Example4()

    Const TEXT = "TXN. NO     TXN SEQ"
    Const TEXT_FILENAME = "D:\SLC.txt"
    Const OUT_FILENAME = "D:\SLC_Copied.xlsx"

    Dim wbText As Workbook, wbOut As Workbook, rngOut As Range
    Dim wsText As Worksheet, wsOut As Worksheet, count As Integer
    Dim rngSearch As Range, rngFound As Range, rowFirstFind As Long

    ' open text file no link update, read only
    Set wbText = Workbooks.Open(TEXT_FILENAME, False, True)
    Set wsText = wbText.Sheets(1)

    ' search
    Set rngSearch = wsText.Columns("A:A")
    Set rngFound = rngSearch.Find(what:=TEXT, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)

    If rngFound Is Nothing Then
        wbText.Close
        MsgBox "No lines match [" & TEXT & "]", vbCritical, "Exiting Sub"
        Exit Sub
    Else

        ' create new workbook for results
        Set wbOut = Workbooks.Add
        Set wsOut = wbOut.Sheets(1)
        Set rngOut = wsOut.Range("A1")
        rowFirstFind = rngFound.Row

        Do
            'Debug.Print rngFound.Row
            rngFound.Offset(3, 0).Resize(20, 1).Copy rngOut
            Set rngOut = rngOut.Offset(20, 0)
            Set rngFound = rngSearch.FindNext(rngFound)
            count = count + 1
        Loop Until rngFound.Row = rowFirstFind

    End If
    wbText.Close False

    wbOut.SaveAs OUT_FILENAME
    MsgBox count & " blocks copied to " & wbOut.Name, vbInformation, "Finished"
    wbOut.Close

End Sub
```